# Not finding name inside table using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search for a Name from the `$_GET[]` variable, I'm using prepared statement but for some reason, I can't find the name, I tested trying to find the ID, and it worked, but for strings, it doesn't seem to work. My database has the column that I'm trying to search as `VARCHAR`.

[image: PHP my admin screenshot]]

Php connection:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "loginsistema";

  $sensor1 = $_GET["s1"]; //Trocar isto por POST
  $sensor2 = $_GET["s2"]; //Trocar isto por POST
  $sensor3 = $_GET["s3"]; //Trocar isto por POST 
  $chave = $_GET['chave']; //Trocar isto por POST 

  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  if ($conn->connect_error){
    die ("Connection failed". $conn->connect_error);
  }

  //Ver se a chave existe nos aparelhos, e para inserir os dados na tabela certa
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM aparelhos WHERE numdserie=?;";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql))
  {
    echo '<script> window.alert("Opa! MySQLI Error Cx!"); </script>";';
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $chave);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
      $dbname = "infosensor";
      $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `1` (chave,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) VALUES ($chave, $sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3);";
    }

  }

  if($conn->query($sql) == TRUE){
    echo "New record created succesfully.</br>";
  }else{
    echo "Error: " .$sql. "</br>" .$conn->error; 
  }

  $conn->close();

  echo "Connected sucessfully.";
?>
```

Comment: Your code is still vulnerable to SQL injection. You should learn how to use prepared statements correctly. See https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli

Answer (score -2):

When your variables are number you can use this code exactly what you have done with id like this:

$sql = "INSERT INTO `1` (chave,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) VALUES ($chave, $sensor1 , $sensor2 , $sensor3);";

but when your variables are text for example you need this code:

$sql = "INSERT INTO `1` (chave,sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) VALUES ('$chave', '$sensor1' , '$sensor2' , '$sensor3');";